# Name Conflict when Building Boost libraries with Cygwin/GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cygwin

I'm in the process of migrating a C++ application from VC++ to GCC (running on Windows using Cygwin). My first problem now is that I cannot build the Boost libraries.

For example to build Boost.Exception with VC++ I would write:

```
b2 --with-exception variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static
```

and I would get the files libboost_exception-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib and libboost_exception-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib in my stage\lib directory.

However when I try the same using GCC form a Cygwin terminal I get errors. I found out that building only debug (or only release) like this works:

```
./b2 --with-exception variant=debug link=static runtime-link=static
```

It creates libboost_exception.a in my stage\lib directory for both cases (debug and release). So there seems to be a name conflict (same name for debug and release variant). Is this a bug in the boost build system or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Edit:**

The output of

```
./b2 --with-exception variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static
```

is:

> Building the Boost C++ Libraries.
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:1079: in virtual-target.register-actual-name from module virtual-target
>
> error: Duplicate name of actual target: libboost_exception.a
>
> error: previous virtual target { common%common.copy-libboost_exception.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.archive-libboost_exception.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.compile.c++-clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.o.OBJ { clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.cpp.CPP } } } }
>
> error: created from ./stage-proper
>   error: another virtual target { common%common.copy-libboost_exception.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.archive-libboost_exception.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.compile.c++-clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.o.OBJ { clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.cpp.CPP } } } }
>
> error: created from ./stage-proper
>
> error: added properties: off NDEBUG full speed off release
>
> error: removed properties: on off off on debug
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:490: in actualize-no-scanner from module object(file-target)@1014
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:135: in object(file-target)@1014.actualize from module object(file-target)@1014
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:749: in load from module build-system
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
>
> /cygdrive/c/boost_1_51_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I will provide the error messages tomorrow when I'm back at work. What I can say now is that the errors appear even before the build system displays the list of libraries it is (not) going to build...

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I added more information to my question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the error message is not perfect, this is operator error. By default, the build uses system naming of library -- the naming you would have on your typical Unix system. So, yea, if you try to build both debug and release variant, you get naming clash.

If you add `--layout=tagged` or `--layout=versioned` to your command line, things should work. You can run "./b2 --help" from the top directory to get some explanation for these mean.

Comment: Why is the default behaviour different for Cygwin/GCC? I think this option should be mentioned in the getting started guide. The getting started guide mentions `--build-type=complete` and describes the library naming pattern. Both does only apply when the libraries are built with `--layout=versioned`. This is not obvious for a newbie. Besides, I did not really get any information about this option with `./b2 --help`

Comment: Actually the default is different for Unix, and Cygwin is deemed a variant of Unix here. Roger about documentation. Did you run --help in the root folder of Boost tree? The help is clearly there for me.